# select case performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

Assume that we have this table:

```
|------------------------------|
| col           | data type    | 
|------------------------------|
| id            | bigint       |
| first_name    | nvarchar     |
| last_name     | nvarchar     |
| photo         | binary       |
|------------------------------|
```

ok now we want two queries for this table:

- list all table rows without photo col(load it as null)
- load specific row with photo col

For this we want to use SP

The first approach going to be like this:

```
SELECT Top 50
    id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    CASE WHEN @id IS NULL THEN null ELSE photo END as photo
FROM MyTable
WHERE @id IS NULL OR id=@id
```

and the second approach is:

```
IF (@id IS NULL)
    SELECT Top 50
        id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        null as photo
    FROM MyTable
ELSE
    SELECT 
        id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        photo
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE id=@id
END
```

The second approach obviously check the if condition one time and do the work.

But I like to write my SPs like first approach and I don't know if sql server going to check the `CASE WHEN @id IS NULL` for each row or the query optimizer going to optimize the query without `CASE`?

Edit 1:

I want to know if the first query would **always** executed without case or not? because it is checking a variable that doesn't change value and its not related to any column value.

Comment: Check the execution plans and compare.

Comment: yes, you are right, but my question is about how this gonna be optimized? this is just an example. thx. @sstan

Comment: Wouldn't the execution plans for the example answer your question about how something like it would be optimized?  Even though it's just an example?

Comment: What @sstan told. But from my experience, having two seperate queries will probably have better performance. SQL Server or any other RDBMS doesn't really like `OR` clauses.

Comment: I've tried execution plan, but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some answers were posted, I decided to check it out for myself.

### Setup on SQL Server 2014

```
-- table is not identical to yours, but it should do.
create table t1 (
  id int identity primary key,
  first_name varchar(50),
  last_name varchar(50)
)
go

-- insert ~10,000,000 rows of randomly generated data.
with cte as (
  select 1 as rn, newid() as first_name, newid() as last_name
  union all
  select t.rn + 1 as rn, newid() as first_name, newid() as last_name
    from cte t
   where t.rn < 10000000
)
insert into t1 (first_name, last_name)
select first_name, last_name
from cte
option (maxrecursion 0)
go

update statistics
go
```

### Query #1 - OP's unified query approach:

```
declare @id int = 5000000

SELECT Top 50
    id,
    first_name,
    last_name
FROM t1
WHERE @id IS NULL OR id = @id
go
```

***Execution time: 13 seconds***

Execution plan:

[image]

### Query #2 - OP's query in the ELSE clause:

```
declare @id int = 5000000

SELECT 
   id,
   first_name,
   last_name
FROM t1
WHERE id=@id
go
```

***Execution time: 0 seconds***

Execution plan:

[image]

### Query #3 - @Ann's query:

```
declare @id int = 5000000

SELECT Top 50
       id,
       first_name,
       last_name
FROM   t1
WHERE  @id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT id,
       first_name,
       last_name
FROM   t1
WHERE  id = @id
go
```

***Execution time: 0 seconds***

Execution plan:

[image]

### Query #4 - @Hogan's query:

```
declare @id int = 5000000

SELECT Top 50
       id,
       first_name,
       last_name
FROM   t1
WHERE  id = COALESCE(@id, id)
go
```

***Execution time: 14 seconds***

Execution plan:

[image]

### Conclusion

Both your attempt, and Hogan's, to unify the logic in a single query don't perform as well as having a separate query for the case where `@id` has a value.  In both cases, you can see that the query essentially scans the whole clustered index, rather than performing the more straight forward index seek.

Interestingly, though Ann's execution plan appears to be the most complex of all, the performance suggests that the optimizer was somehow able to detect that `@id` was not null and short-circuit the expensive cluster index scan in that case.

Still, since you're already inside a stored procedure, it seems to me that you should stick with the `if-else` approach. Seems like the safest way to go.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

You could try this, which avoids the `CASE` and also the `IF`.  I'll admit, though, that it's a little cryptic.

```
SELECT Top 50
       id,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       null as photo
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  @id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT id,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       photo
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  id = @id
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this (have null parameter default to all) is like this:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    photo
FROM MyTable
WHERE id=COALESCE(@id,id)
```

In my experience this gives good performance on all major platforms if there is an index on ID